# Django, redirect to another view with data

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm sending a form. So if it's valid i'm setting a variable `message` with a message. So if the form is valid, I would like to redirect to another view but also pass the `message` variable. It should be a syntax issue.

On successful submission, it redirects to a view with a url `membership/enroll/studies.views.dashboard` which of course is wrong.

views.py

```
def enroll(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SelectCourseYear(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            student = form.save(commit=False)
            student.user = request.user
            student.save()
            message = 'Successfully Enrolled'
        return redirect('studies.views.dashboard', {'message': message,})
    else:
        form = SelectCourseYear()
    return render(request, 'registration/step3.html',)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider making use of sessions to store arbitrary data between requests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

```
request.session['message'] = 'Successfully Enrolled'
```

Alternatively, if you just want to display a message to the user, you might be happy with the contrib.messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.success(request, 'Successfully Enrolled')
```

Based on your use case above, I'm guessing that contrib.messages is more appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Correct! I used the second one. I think messages is more relevant to giving a `Succesfull` alert! Thank you!